# Accumulating plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to create a graph form 0% to 100% on the x axis and
units on the y, and accumulate from y=0 to y=max, so I can say "X of
my elements occured within the first Y units". Is there a predefined
stat in ggplot2 which allows me to do that?

Here's some data: http://sprunge.us/XYJK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either apply it before processing with ggplot or during:

For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(XML) 
x <- eval(parse(file("http://sprunge.us/XYJK"))) # Your data
d <- data.frame(x=x,y=1:length(x)) 
d$z <- cumsum(d$x) / sum(d$x) # As percent

ggplot(d, aes(z,y)) + geom_line() + scale_x_continuous(label=percent)
```

OR

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
d <- data.frame(x=x,y=1:100)
ggplot(d, aes(cumsum(x)/sum(x),y) + geom_line() + scale_x_continuous(label=percent)
```

I'm assuming this is sales data or something like that. So putting it in that context, 50% of revenue occurs from the first 5000 transactions.

Comment: Now that I think about it, geom_area() may be more appropriate.

Comment: I assume `x` or `y` is my measurement variable - I have about 10k of them, see edit.

Comment: `y` is just a counter, `x` is your measurement. I've updated it to show your data.

Comment: Are you sure the graph is correct? I expected the line to be more hyperbolic.

Comment: I'm not at all sure. You'll have to be more specific about what it is that we are plotting. Context matters.

Comment: The context is that I'm assigning a geolocation to documents and I want to show the difference between my method and the baseline, which has the most effect in close range (aka <50 km). The data is the error per document in km.

Comment: Looking @Dennis answer, you could also use stat='ecdf', `ggplot(d,aes(x,y)) + geom_line(stat='ecdf')`

Comment: Yes, this looks like what I was looking for \o/.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me as though you're looking for an empirical CDF. Your data have replicated values in a number of places, so I created the empirical CDF based on a frequency table of the sorted values. I copied your data into a vector x and then did the following:

```
tf <- as.data.frame(table(x), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
tf <- within(tf, {
          Var1 <- as.numeric(Var1)
          pct <- 100 * cumsum(Freq)/sum(Freq)
                 } )
ggplot(tf, aes(x = Var1, y = pct)) + 
    geom_step(size = 1) +
    labs(x = "Value", y = "Cumulative percentage")
```

The problem is that your data are so heavily right skewed that the histogram emulates a hyperbolic curve, so the vast majority of the data is well under 1000 with several serious outliers. To give you an idea,

```
quantile(x, c(0.005, 0.01, 0.05, 0.10, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9, 0.95, 0.99, 0.995))
   0.5%          1%          5%         10%         25%         50% 
 1.64425      2.79850     7.54500    11.77500    21.76000    39.35000 
    75%         90%         95%         99%       99.5% 
 73.28000   398.05000   1695.78750 10499.99000 11638.55600
```

and

```
summary(tst$y)
Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
0.00    21.76    39.35   434.90    73.28 18520.00
```

The mean is larger than the 90th percentile of the distribution! In that context, I don't think an ecdf plot is going to be very informative. To find out what proportion of values in your vector is less than or equal to a given value, try the following small function:

```
cumprop <- function(x, val) mean(x <= val)
cumprop(x, 1000)
cumprop(x, mean(x))  # proportion of values <= mean(x)
```

Comment: I considered plotting only the values from 0 to 100, that way you can actually see something. And replicated == identical? That's to be expected.